# VSCode - There is a red underline but the program builds and runs correctly, and dubugging error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have configured my vscode to use c++ on Linux. Recently i want to write a new cpp program, I followed the MS VScode tutorial, but when I copy the code to VScode, there is a red underline and hint like this:
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHvuN.png)

However, I can build it and even run it correctly without error:[run build tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks6bK.png) [run it in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdEuO.png)

When I debug it, the error occurs.

```
{
    "resource": "/home/aqachun/Documents/Projects/cpp/vscodeTest/helloworld.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "no instance of constructor \"std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector [with _Tp=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::string>]\" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (const char [6], const char [4], const char [6], const char [5], const char [8], const char [23])",
    "startLineNumber": 9,
    "startColumn": 24,
    "endLineNumber": 9,
    "endColumn": 24
}
```

this is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/backward",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "cStandard": "c11"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

   for (const string& word : msg)
   {
      cout << word << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like an intellisense error.

Comment: That error is actually a build failure, so your claim that you can build must be a misinterpretation. At least that's what I think. If you described what you did and what you observed, people could give a better diagnosis. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you, I have updated my question with two images about run build task and run program, does it seem to run well?

Comment: Interesting, this compiles fine for me with clang++-9

Comment: I also get no such error in vscode

Comment: @Zichen Huang try it with std:: before vector and string (to be explicit) and if that doesnt work try resetting/reinstalling vscode as I cant reproduce this

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23: thank you, I try your solution but the error still, I can't find out the reason and now I clear my `settings.json`, dumb but it works, now there is no problem with the code.

Comment: @ZichenHuang, I am facing the same problem on MS Windows 10 using /msys64/mingw64/ ; so +1 ;  Shows exactly same error on editor, It compiles fine but does not gives any output.  Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: could the problem be that you're using `"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc"` instead of `"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++"`? (c compiler instead of c++ compiler) also, what do you mean by "when I debug it the error occurs"? the screenshot you're showing shows no debugging- just what appears to be an initellisense error.

Answer (score 1):

I also did that tutorial (for Linux) and have no such error.
This is my c_cpp_properties.json file and I think maybe its because you don't have your IntelliSense made specified. Try mine c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

And this is my settings.json:

```
{
"files.associations": {
    "array": "cpp",
    "atomic": "cpp",
    "*.tcc": "cpp",
    "cctype": "cpp",
    "clocale": "cpp",
    "cmath": "cpp",
    "cstdarg": "cpp",
    "cstddef": "cpp",
    "cstdint": "cpp",
    "cstdio": "cpp",
    "cstdlib": "cpp",
    "cwchar": "cpp",
    "cwctype": "cpp",
    "deque": "cpp",
    "unordered_map": "cpp",
    "vector": "cpp",
    "exception": "cpp",
    "algorithm": "cpp",
    "memory": "cpp",
    "memory_resource": "cpp",
    "optional": "cpp",
    "string": "cpp",
    "string_view": "cpp",
    "system_error": "cpp",
    "tuple": "cpp",
    "type_traits": "cpp",
    "utility": "cpp",
    "fstream": "cpp",
    "initializer_list": "cpp",
    "iosfwd": "cpp",
    "iostream": "cpp",
    "istream": "cpp",
    "limits": "cpp",
    "new": "cpp",
    "ostream": "cpp",
    "sstream": "cpp",
    "stdexcept": "cpp",
    "streambuf": "cpp",
    "typeinfo": "cpp"
}
```

}

My launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
```

}

Maybe changing those settings files will help. Mine work

Comment: thank you, I try to set the `"intelliSenseMode"` to `"clang-x64"`, but the error still. Then I change my `"includePath"` to `"${workspaceFolder}/**"`, I get a`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. `, When clicking the bulb to add the includePath it said to add, the original error again. Maybe i should configure my c/cpp extension?

Comment: Check if you have clang (you can easily install it on Linux) just go `whereis clang` if you have it installed a path to it will appear if not go `sudo apt-get install clang`.
You can use clang its a normal, good compiler. Also, make sure you have those extensions that enable IntelliSense installed